# AppEngine/NDB How to apply a query filter against single entity

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

In our app we often have several query filters that check things like archive status, permission, entity hierarchy, etc. These filters are built using NDB's operator overloads, e.g. `models.Item.isArchived == False`. I believe these are also referred to as `FilterNode` instances.

Given a set of these FilterNodes how can I apply them to a single entity that has been looked up outside of a query? Say from Memcache.

My use case is I have a predefined set of filters for an endpoint and the service allows the user to specify an entity ID. Rather than run a query, I do a get by ID. But I need to post filter to sure it's valid to return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a couple of ways to do in-memory filtering using a Query object (both of these assume NDB... but can be modified for non)

this first one just uses Python builtin "filter()"... it doesn't handle sort-orders that may be in the query:

```
def filter_entities(query, entities):
  #convert entities to list of protocol buffers
  entity_pbs = [ent._to_pb() for ent in entities if ent is not None]

  #assuming all entities are same type... just get type from first one
  model_klass = type(entities[0])

  #turn the query into a filter and hand it to builtin
  filtered = filter(query.filters._to_filter(), entity_pbs)

  #convert protocol buffers back into entities and hand back
  return [klass._from_pb(ent) for ent in filtered if ent is not None]
```

This other approach uses apply_query from datastore_query... which *will* take sort orders into account:

```
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import tasklets
from google.appengine.datastore.datastore_query import apply_query

def apply_query(query, entities):
  #convert list of entities to list of protocol buffers
  entity_pbs = [ent._to_pb() for ent in entities if ent is not None]

  #convert NDB query to datastore_query (needs connection)
  conn = tasklets.get_context()._conn
  dsquery = query._get_query(conn)

  #call datastore_query.apply_query
  filtered = apply_query(dsquery, [entity_pbs])

  #convert protocol buffers back into entities and hand back
  return [klass._from_pb(ent) for ent in filtered if ent is not None]
```

clearly I'm accessing some hidden methods that could change in the future... and so be sure you've written tests to catch that possibility